# HTML tags selectively stripped out

Tags: javascript, html

On the results page of [this quiz](http://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/quiz/), when you get an answer wrong, there's explanatory text given. For some reason, html tags like `<strong>` are stripped out of that text, even though they display correctly everywhere else in the quiz. I've checked both js files but can't find the culprit. Any ideas?

I'm trying to add formatting in this line of [Q/A js](http://www.lawlessfrench.com/wp-content/themes/cassie/js/quiz-telling-time.js)

```
$('#quiz-form').append('<p class="special" id="special_'+key+'" ><strong>Correct answer(s): '+answer+'</strong> '+special+'</p>');
```

Comment: try replacing the " with &quot;

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the " with this `&quot;` in this Q/A.js file for content

this link has list the characters which

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

check this example

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/s777qqu6/4/)

Comment: no it will not break you made a mistake you also replaced the " for style check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/s777qqu6/3/ @freefaller

Comment: Yes, I didn't use backticks and someone corrected it for me. I'm trying to get some text in "special" to show as bold.